# core libvlc error while creating an instance for vlc

Tags: python, binding, instance, vlc, libvlc

I want to make a simple media player in python using the libvlc python bindings. I have downloaded the vlc.py and tested it. It works perfectly. So I started using vlc.py as a module in my code, here is my code:

    `import dev_vlc as vlc
    import time
    import os
    vlcinstance = vlc.Instance()
    myplayer = vlcinstance.media_player_new()
    media = vlcinstance.media_new('test.mp3')
    myplayer.set_media(media)
    myplayer.play()
    time.sleep(10)`

When I run the above code instead of playing the audio file it throws the following error:

`[034a2cb4] core libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/krush/Documents/MyMediaPlayer/MyMediaPlayer.py", line 7, in <module>
    myplayer = vlcinstance.media_player_new()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'`

Can anyone please help me to fix and tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: You haven't "gone wrong". The first line of the error tells you that the issue is with your installation of `vlc`. Address that and the code will function.

Comment: Got it, I have copied the libvlc.dll and other required dll files to the corresponding working directory. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is checking for libvlc.dll and other couple of dll files, which were not included in my installed version of VLC (may be due to some issues during installation or any other reason. IDK).

So copying the dlls to VLC installation folder or working directory of the project solved the problem.